How to fetch the fist single record based on criteria from PostgreSQL with Gorm (Grails)
I have a table in ProstgreSQL that collects activity records.
There is job that needs to process all of these records one by one into a different format. For that, we need to fetch the oldest (first) record from the table for processing.
I seem to be confused about how to do it correctly. What I did for now it's this. I am getting a list of one, and then grabbing the first element of it.
Optional<RawActivity> getEarliestRaw() {
        RawActivity[] activities = RawActivity.createCriteria().list {
            isNull "processedAt"
            order("lastUpdated", "asc")
            maxResults 1
        } as RawActivity[]

        Optional.ofNullable(activities.length > 0 ? activities.head() : null)
    }

It works, but I feel there must be a better way.

Just fetching the record...
RawActivity.createCriteria().get {
    min('lastUpdated')
}

With possible other field...
RawActivity findOldest(final String user) {
    RawActivity.createCriteria().get {
        resultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(RawActivity))
        if ( user ) {
            eq('user', user)
        }
        projections {
            property('user', 'user')
            min('lastUpdated', 'lastUpdated')
        }
    }
}


What about the other conditions when I have them? For example, the last record for a user...

Just add a clause eq('user', yourUser) - https://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/index.html#criteria

K But, isn't the max going to be relative to the entire collection instead of taking the clauses into consideration?

When adding say user the min doesn't work unless it's in a projections block which then returns the date. Adding a resultTransformer to convert to something else, in this case the RawActivity works but you have to fetch fields in the projections to fill out the object. Might not be suitable if you need to return an entire large domain object but maybe okay if you just fetch a few fields into a simplified object.
